# Network services hang

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, services

Every time something changes in my network, like router restart, changing WiFi networks, etc... the network interfaces just stop responding.
The networks button in notification area just does nothing when clicked, Network and Sharing center won't start and everything uses the internet just don't work (don't receive responses).
The only solution I found to that is to go the svchost that runs netman and kill it.
Stopping netman in services won't do anything, it will still appear running.
Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Simple reboot should do the trick.

Comment: @George I know how to fix it every time, but I want it to go away.